# Noobish question about USDT and ETH

Tags: tokens

I want to have some USDT and send that to my metamask account. If I have only USDT on my empty metamask account can I sed that USDT to another person without having ETH for the gas price? Cause other coins I used like Bitcoin and Litecoin always payed in their own currency the network price, but if I'll have USDT on my metamask account will I pay in USDT or I have to have USDT plus some ETH for the network price?

Comment: You need Ether.

Comment: Oh thank you goodvibration it was new information for me. So good I not collected USDT for that acc first without ETH. Now I'm even more sure how things works.

Comment: BTW, there are tokens on Ethereum that could be sent from an account without necessity for this account to ever hold any ether.  [EURS](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdb25f211ab05b1c97d595516f45794528a807ad8), for example.